# In OBIEE, how do I connect a Data Source to some custom PL/SQL code that returns the data?

Tags: sql, datasource, business-intelligence, obiee

In OBIEE, I am trying to create a report that displays payment data. I have already created the PL/SQL code , which fills a table which is in the OBIEE database. However, I don't know how to add it to a data source so that I can make a report.

[image]

I am maybe missing the concept of how OBIEE works, but where can I find the custom table I created . any tips appreciated,thansk

Comment: I think I have figured this out - there's a way to directly execute sql code in OBIEE  - I ran a sample code with colleague and it worked

Comment: That's BI Publisher by the way, not OBIEE ;-)

Comment: @Coffee, you are referring to Direct Database Requests. Please answer your own question with the steps that you ran with your colleague (for posterity). To learn more about DDRs, please read this:
https://medium.com/red-pill-analytics/pardirect-database-request-6fa4d668bab8